# How to recognize stl containers within a function template?

Tags: templates, c++11, stl

What I'm trying to do is to define a function template such that if the typename represents a container it recurses applying itself on the elements, something like:

```
template<typename T> 
function void apply( T &t ){
    if( is_container<T>::value )
        for( auto &e : t ) apply(e);
    else
        // do something to t
        t = ...;
}
```

I have looked in the `<type_traits>` header, but I'm not sure if there is something there I can use.

For my own classes I would like to be able to control if it has to behave like a container or like an element.

Does somebody know if there is a nice way to do this?

Comment: Do you need that to be specifically STL container, or any container, including plain array, for which range for loop compiles?

Comment: I would like it to work with `array<T, N> a` but I don't mind if it gives a positive answer to `T a[N]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you can't do this.

The problem is that every line in your function template has to be valid syntax even if the argument *isn't* a container. In your code the `for (auto &e : t)` part will probably not compile when `is_container<T>::value` is false, so the entire function fails to compile.

There have been some proposals for a "static if" that would allow entire blocks of code to be conditionally ignored by the compiler, based on compile-time constants, but they have serious issues (see [Static If Considered](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3613.pdf) for links to proposals and discussions of problems with them).

The safe and portable way to solve your problem is to dispatch to a different function depending on which block of code you want to run:

```
template<typename T> 
  void apply( T &t );   // forward declaration

template<typename T> 
  void apply2( T &t, std::true_type ){
    for( auto &e : t ) apply(e);
  }

template<typename T> 
  void apply2( T &t, std::false_type ){
    // do something to t
    t = ...;
  }

template<typename T> 
  void apply( T &t ){
    apply2(t, std::integral_constant<bool, is_container<T>::value>() );
  }
```

This ensures that the code that only works if `T` is a container will only ever get called when `T` really is a container. This is called [tag dispatching](http://www.boost.org/community/generic_programming.html#tag_dispatching).

Now to make this work all you need is a trait `is_container`, which is pretty easy to write once you decide what you mean by container :-)

There's no standard "is container" type trait, but if you decide that your definition of "container" is something that has `begin()` and `end()` members, you can write a trait to test for them:

```
template<typename T>
struct is_container_helper
{
  template<typename U,
           typename Require1 = decltype(std::declval<const U&>().begin()),
           typename Require2 = decltype(std::declval<const U&>().end())>
    static std::true_type test(const U*);

  template<typename U>
    static std::false_type test(...);

  typedef decltype(test<T>(0)) type;
};

template<typename T>
struct is_container : is_container_helper<T>::type { };
```

Given this trait you can then specialize it for your own types.

Alternatively, you can use [SFINAE](http://accu.org/content/conf2013/Jonathan_Wakely_sfinae.pdf) instead of tag dispatching, which is the trick that makes the `is_container_helper` trait above work. That will not allow you to specialize the trait for you own types so easily.

Comment: This is more of an `is_range` than `is_container`, in which case I would prefer non-member `begin` and `end`: `typename Require1 = decltype(std::begin(std::declval<const U&>()))`. ([Live at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/307fd6877c2fc387))

Comment: Agreed. The point of my answer was that the OP's function template will not work even with a correct `is_container`, rather than showing a correct `is_container`.

Answer (score -1):

I think traditionally if a type contains a `value_type` typedef then it's a container.

Alternatively, you can look for the `iterator` typedef, that might be more robust.

Comment: You haven't said how to create a trait based on the presence of those types, nor have you said how to make the OP's function template work (which as written is impossible even if you have an `is_container` trait) so the answer isn't very useful.